# Difference between autoprefixer used in bootstrap and the grunt-autoprefixer from gruntjs plugin page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs, autoprefixer

Why doesn't bootstrap use grunt-autoprefixer ?

Why do they use the other one?

What are their differences?

And which one should I use for my own projects?

/Confused

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap does use the `grunt-autoprefixer` as seen [on the package.json](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/package.json#L37).

If you want to have the exact same results, you can aim the same browsers as Bootstrap does

```
"autoprefixerBrowsers": [
  "Android 2.3",
  "Android >= 4",
  "Chrome >= 20",
  "Firefox >= 24",
  "Explorer >= 8",
  "iOS >= 6",
  "Opera >= 12",
  "Safari >= 6"
]
```

(As they are in [configBridge.json](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/grunt/configBridge.json#L21))

Add them to your `gruntFile`

```
autoprefixer: {
  options: {
    browsers: [
      "Android 2.3",
      "Android >= 4",
      "Chrome >= 20",
      "Firefox >= 24",
      "Explorer >= 8",
      "iOS >= 6",
      "Opera >= 12",
      "Safari >= 6"
    ]
  },
  /** your subtasks here **/
}
```